# aws-amplify CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider SSO for Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, single-sign-on, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

on react, i am currently trying to create an sso button to connect to azure, i am only doing the front end for now and created a try/catch method with onclick function.

Yet it is not directing me to azure but loging me in like the button above, for now all i want to achieve is everytime i click the button it will redirect me to azure using the CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider function provided by aws amplify

i already am aware of all the official documentation but i am currently using the v4 of amplify and therefor do not have access to its documentation, online there is only the v5 and 6

i have spent more than a day on it and i am at a point where i feel close but i am still missing something, any input will be greatly appreciated

```
azureSSO = async () => {
    try {
        await Auth.federatedSignIn({
    provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Azure,
    });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error initiating Azure SSO:", error); }
    };

return(<Button
    type="submit"
    className="auth-btn"
    size="sm"
    style={{ color: "#fff" }}>  
        {this.props.isFetching ? "Loading..." : "Aspace"}</Button>
    <Button
         type="submit"
         className="auth-btn"
     size="sm"
     style={{ color: "#fff" }}
     onClick={this.azureSSO}    
        >
    {this.props.isFetching ? "Loading..." : "SSO with Azure"} </Button>
)
```